# wget in microsoft/nanoserver:1709

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, nano-server

I tried to run create an `nicrosoft/nanoserver:1709` with `wget` inside of it.
So I made a Dockerfile that moves the `wget.exe` from my computer to the image, that looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/nanoserver:
COPY wget.exe C:\\Windows\\System32\\wget.exe
```

When I tried to ran the wget it done nothing.
Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/362152/native-alternative-to-wget-in-windows-powershell